# Selenium - Can't click link having onclick event

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

So this is the link I'm trying to click:

```
<a class="nav-link text-light" href="#" onclick="return hydra.dissent.selectCommentsTab(event, 'top', {"url":"https://www.some-website.com/","v":"begin","uid":"5xxxxxxx5f2bc7d4b7","s":"controversial","p":1,"cpp":10});">Top</a>
```

I fetched it using `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav-link.text-light")` and verified it by using `get_attribute("innerText")` and it did show `Top`.

 But when I try `.click()` on it, nothing seems to happen.

 I also tried `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` and that didn't work either.

 Then I tried `driver.execute_script("<onclick_text_here>")`; still no luck.

 The code doesn't throw any error either, so I don't know what the issue is.

 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click on the link?

Comment: @itronic1990 there is a ```div``` for comments in the page. It has 4 categories. The ```a``` tag is used to change the category and display in new comments in the ```div``` .

Answer (score 0):

```
href="#"
```

basically means even if you `click`, it won't redirect you anywhere.

and text also says `Top`, may be when you click it scroll till `Top` which can be achieved by many ways in Selenium.

Comment: My intention is not to redirect. I just want the ```onclick``` event to be fired when I interact with the element, and that is what I'm unable to achieve

Comment: Can you share URL ?